# Непонятка с Google Payments Merchant Center

Tags: android

Ребята, пожалуйста подскажите, есть ли у кого сейчас такая ситуация в Payments Merchant Center в разделе Транзакции?

У меня уже так 2 дня висит, и что напрягает, так то, что завтра день вывода средств, а Google вот так делает. Успокойте меня, скажите, не повлияет ли это на вывод средств?

[image: трабл]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое бывает с периодичностью раз в пару месяцев. Обычно проходит в течение 10-48 часов. Просто подождите. Сейчас, вся статистика уже доступна.